# Isolating images and content

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm looking to separate the text and images in my Wordpress post. I want to be able to put them in different areas on my page.

I currently have only been able to get the content in

tags but can't isolate and separate the content.

current html

```
<?php
  $content = wpautop($content); // Add paragraph-tags
  $content = str_replace('<p></p>', '', $content); // remove empty paragraphs
  $content = preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<a .*>)?\s*(<img .* \/>)\s*(<\/a>)?\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1\2\3', $content); // remove paragraphs around img tags
  echo $content;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated based on your comment.

You can get all the content with no images.

```
$content = get_the_content();
$text = wp_strip_all_tags( $content );
```

And to get the images you can get all the URLs inside of an array.

```
$re = '/<img .+? src="(.+?)"/i';
preg_match_all( $re, $content, $images );
// images url are located on $images[1]
```

Comment: I'm looking to get all the words, and then get all the images in the post. So that I can put the images in one place, and the text in another

Comment: Updated based on your comments.

Comment: ok cool, just a couple of questions. 1. So I just have to echo $content and/or $re as I have done. 2. will the content strip out lists, blockquotes etc?